# How to hash and add salt to password from csv C#

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, password-protection

I am a student totally new to C# programming. I am currently doing a mini security project using MVC. The project:
Allow users to upload a csv file containing accounts but password not hash and salt. (Done)
Then I will send the file to virustotal and scan it before saving to the server (Done)
After saving, I need to insert the data in the csv file and hash and salt the password into the database. (Need help)

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Equals(".csv"))
        {
            //{0} = Y, {1} = M, {2} = D, {3} = H, {4} = min, {5} = Sec
            string datetime = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}-{3}{4}{5}", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
            string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.csv", file.FileName.Substring(0, (file.FileName.Length - 4)), datetime);
            var fileStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);

            var vtObj = new VirusTotal("%API KEY%");
            vtObj.UseTLS = true;
            try
            {
                var fileResults = vtObj.ScanFile(fileStream, fileName);
                var report = vtObj.GetFileReport(fileResults.ScanId);

                int resPos = report.Positives;

                if (resPos == 0)
                {
                    string savePath = Server.MapPath("~/CSV/" + fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(savePath);
                    try
                    {
                        //removing the first row
                        insertDB(fileName, savePath);
                        ViewBag.error = "Updated successfully";
                        return View();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ViewBag.error = "Unable to update DB" + ex;
                        return View("Index");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.error = "Unable to upload";
                    return View("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.error = string.Format("Unable to upload | One min only can upload 4 times | {0} | {1}", ex, fileName);
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.error = "Unable to upload";
            return View("Index");
        }
    }

    public void insertDB(string fileName, string savePath)
    {

        using (DB01Entities dbc = new DB01Entities())
        {
            string sql = string.Format(@"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempImport]
                                        (
                                            Name varchar(255),
                                            Password VARBINARY(50)
                                        )

                                        bulk insert [dbo].[TempImport] from '%MyPATH%\CSV\{0}' with (ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

                                        INSERT INTO dbo.Employee
                                        (
                                            Name
                                            Password
                                        )
                                        SELECT  name
                                        FROM       dbo.TempImport

                                        DROP TABLE dbo.TempImport", fileName);
            dbc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
            dbc.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**My Index**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input type="file" name="File" id="file" accept=".csv"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
<div class="error">@ViewBag.error</div>
}
```

**Upload**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

<div class="success">@ViewBag.error</div>
<a href="/Home/Index">Back to Index>></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a bulk insert via SQL is not a requirement:

Since you're using ASP.NET, use the [Crypto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.aspx) class to hash your passwords:

```
var hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(plainTextPassword);
```

When you want to verify the plain text version later, use

```
bool matches = Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, plainTextPassword);
```

The hashed password contains the salt used when hashing, and Crypto knows how to extract the salt from the password hash.

Since you have a stream to read from:

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    using (DB01Entities dbc = new DB01Entities())
    {
        while(reader.Peek != -1)
        {
            var parts = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
            var hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(parts[1]);
            dbc.Employees.Add(new Employee { Name = parts[0], Password = hashedPassword });
        }

        dbc.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This also has the advantage of not requiring the file to be saved anywhere, as you can just use the bytes you already have in memory.

Comment: This solution is good, it uses `Crypto.HashPassword` which is a secure method because it includes iteration of the hash.

Comment: Hello, but the I cannot convert string to byte[] at "Password = hashedPassword"

Answer (score -1):

**Change the SQL statement and with that add a static salt to it**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempImport] (
Name varchar(50)
Password varchar(50)
)
bulk insert [dbo].[TempImport] from '%Abs_Path%' with (ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee
(
Name
Password
)
SELECT Name, HASHBYTES('SHA1', (Password+'+_)(*&^%$#@!')) FROM  dbo.TempImport
DROP TABLE dbo.TempImport
```

Comment: Do not do this, just adding a salt no longer provides sufficient security. See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

Comment: 1. Do not use SHA-1, use a SHA-2 function such as SHA-256. 2. Do not use  a static salt, every entry that uses the same password will have the same salt so when one is discovered all others are also exposed, use a random salt that is also saved in the DB. 3. Do not just concatenate the salt, use an HMAC function. 4. it is necessary to iterate the hashing function because calculating hashes is very fast. 5. Use standard password derivation functions such as `Crypto.HashPassword`, `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `bcrypt`, script and etc.